# No provider for String

Tags: typescript, angular

Hi can somebody tell Me what am I doing wrong?
I think it's simple error, but I'm new to angular and I can't find it.

> EXCEPTION: No provider for String! (SwNavItemCmp -> String)

```js
export interface SwNavItemModel {
 name: string;
  route: string;
  children?: Array<SwNavItemModel>;
}
```

```js
import {SwNavItemModel} from '../models/sw_nav_item_model';

export const NAV_ITEMS_DATA: Array<SwNavItemModel> = [
  { name: 'Home',
   route: '/Home' },
  { name: 'Offer',
    route: '/Offer',
   children: [
      { name: 'Prices',
       route: '/Prices' },
      { name: 'Samples',
        route: '/Samples' }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'About',
    route: '/About',
    children: [
      { name: 'Us',
        route: '/Us' },
      { name: 'Projects',
        route: '/Projects' },
      { name: 'Skills',
        route: '/Skills' }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'Contact',
    route: '/Contact' }
];
```

```js
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {NAV_ITEMS_DATA} from '../data/mock_nav_data';


@Injectable()
export class NavService {
 getNavData() {
  return Promise.resolve(NAV_ITEMS_DATA);
 }
}
```

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {
ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
} from 'angular2/router';
import {SwNavItemCmp} from './sw-nav-item/sw_nav_item';
import {SwNavItemModel} from '../../../models/sw_nav_item_model';
import {NavService} from '../../../services/nav_service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sw-nav',
  templateUrl: './components/shared/sw-nav/sw_nav.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/shared/sw-nav/sw_nav.css'],
  providers: [NavService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SwNavItemCmp]
})
export class SwNavCmp implements OnInit {
  public items: Array<SwNavItemCmp> = [];

  constructor(private _navService: NavService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.getNavData();
  }

  getNavData() {
      this._navService.getNavData().then((navData: Array<SwNavItemModel>) => {
          console.log(navData);
          console.log(Object.keys(navData));
          this.addItems(navData);
      });
  }

  addItem(name: string, route: string, children?: Array<SwNavItemModel>) {
    console.log();
    console.log('name: ' + name);
    console.log('route: ' + route);
    console.log('children: ' + children);
    if(children) {
      let childrenItems: Array<SwNavItemCmp> = [];
      console.log('childrenItems: ' + childrenItems);
      children.forEach((child) => {
        console.log('child: ' + child);
        childrenItems.push(new SwNavItemCmp(child.name, child.route, null));
        console.log('childrenItems: ' + childrenItems);
      });
      this.items.push(new SwNavItemCmp(name, route, childrenItems));
      console.log('Items: ' + this.items);
    } else {
      this.items.push(new SwNavItemCmp(name, route, null));
      console.log('Items: ' + this.items);
    }
  }

  addItems(itemsArray: Array<SwNavItemModel>) {
    console.log('ItemsArray: ' + itemsArray);
    itemsArray.forEach((item) => {
      console.log('item: ' + item);
      item.children ? this.addItem(item.name, item.route, item.children) : this.addItem(item.name, item.route, null);
    });
    console.log('Items: ' + this.items);
  }
}
```

```js
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'sw-nav-item',
  templateUrl: './components/shared/sw-nav/sw-nav-item/sw_nav_item.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/shared/sw-nav/sw-nav-item/sw_nav_item.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SwNavItemCmp {
 @Input() items: Array<SwNavItemCmp>;
  name: string;
  route: string;
  children: Array<SwNavItemCmp> = [];
  constructor(name: string, route: string, children?: Array<SwNavItemCmp>) {
    this.name = name;
    this.route = route;
    this.children = children;
  }
}
```

```
constructor(name: string, route: string, children?: Array) {...

throw error TS2314: Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Now I have this:

sw_nav.ts

```
...
export class SwNavCmp implements OnInit {
  public items: Array<SwNavItemCmp> = [];
  ...
}
```

sw_nav.html

```
    <nav>
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li *ngFor="#item of items">
            <sw-nav-item [items]="item.children"></sw-nav-item>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

questions:
-Should I pass whole item insted of item.children?

sw_nav_item.ts

```
import {Component, Input, Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'sw-nav-item',
  templateUrl: './components/shared/sw-nav/sw-nav-item/sw_nav_item.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/shared/sw-nav/sw-nav-item/sw_nav_item.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Injectable()
export class SwNavItemCmp {
  @Input() items: Array<SwNavItemCmp>;

  name: string;
  route: string;
  children: Array<SwNavItemCmp>;

  constructor(name, route, @Inject(SwNavItemCmp) children: Array<SwNavItemCmp>) {
    this.name = name;
    this.route = route;
    this.children = children;
  }
}
```

questions:
-How should constructor looks like? I think it's invalid.
-How to pass data from input to constructor?
-Should I use `Injector.resolveAndCreateChild()` to assing children items?

sw-nav-item.html

???

questions:
-How to render it recursive?
I want to render all sw-nav-item be itself.

And main questions:
 -Where should I put var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate(...
 provide(...), and how should it looks like?
 -If I have wrong structure or concept. How to do it right way? I mean recursive components creation and rendreing.

Comment: Something i wrong in my constructor of SwNavItemCmp, but i don't understand what and why.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

> -How should constructor looks like? I think it's invalid.

The constructor should list the arguments you want to get passed in by Angulars dependency injection (DI). DI can pass values where it has a provider registered in bootstrap (`bootstrap(AppComponent, [SomeProvider, ...])`)

> -How to pass data from input to constructor? -Should I use Injector.resolveAndCreateChild() to assing children items?

I don't know what you mean by "input" or "children items" here.
You don't need `Injector.resolveAndCreateChild()`

-How to render it recursive? I want to render all sw-nav-item be itself.

I don't understand the question. How is that related to the constructor?

> -Where should I put var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate(... provide(...),

As mentioned above, you don't need that.

> and how should it looks like? -If I have wrong structure or concept. How to do it right way? I mean recursive components creation and rendreing.

You don't need the constructor for this.
If you want to pass data from parent to children use binding

```
<!-- in parent component -->
<some-element [someInput]="someValueFromParent">

@Component({
   selector: 'child-component',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() someInput;

  constructor() {
    // here Angular hasn't yet assigned the `someValueFromParent`
  }

  ngOnInit() [
    // here or in event handlers I can access `someInput` and
    // `someValueFromParent` is assigned
  }
}
```

**Original**

The `name` and `route` parameters have no providers.

```
constructor(name: string, route: string, children?: Array<SwNavItemCmp>) {
```

You can't have parameters in components constructors without telling DI what to pass in.

What's the purpose of these parameters?

Comment: I want to set type of name and route parameters as string and children as SwNavItemCmp(self,  so i don't need DI). Why do I need provider for string? Isn't string global type accessible everywhere? The purpose of this parameters is to limit acceptable types in constructor.

Comment: I would need an explanation why these parameters are there. What was the intention? Why did you add them? Only Angulars dependency injection can pass argument values to comonents. Check the articles listed under https://www.google.at/search?q=angular+2+dependency+injection for introductory information.

Comment: I used to think about constructors like in c++, where you can have many of them with different parameters. And i thought it's similar in typescript angular. I know now I was wrong. The idea is to create SwNavItemCmp's in SwNavCmp, and then send them to the input in SwNavItemCmp and assing them to children property of SwNavItemCmp. In the end create method to dynamicly adding new SwNavItemCmp in future. I'am changing my code now, so i send new snippets soon.

Comment: I don't know TypeScript and what features it provides related to constructors. I use only Dart. In Dart you can have many constructors as well, but the default constructor can only have arguments Angulars DI can provide. I don't see a need to pass components as constructor arguments. Angular creates instances of components on demand. If the template contains a tag that is associated to a selector of a component and that component is listed in the `@Component({directives: [SomeComponent]})`, it will create an instance.

Comment: If you want to pass **data** down to children use either binding like explained in my updated answer or use a shared service you register in providers of your parent component and inject it to the constructor of the child (if a component is added by the router to a `router-outlet` you can't use binding).

Comment: I just saw this question in a comment above "Isn't string global type accessible everywhere? The purpose of this parameters is to limit acceptable types in constructor." `string` is a global type, but DI has no information what value it should pass for this string argument.